# Pushing data from a 1d array to a 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a 2d array with the contents of a 1d array. The 2d array has the correct amount of rows and columns, however, each index of the 2d array contains the entirety of the original 1d array.

How can I turn the 1d array:

```
var OneD = [ "Bristol", "Cardiff", "Birmingham",
             "Luton", "Swansea", "Aberdeen",
             "Birmingham", "Manchester", "Southampton", 
             "Chester", "Swansea", "Brighton",
             "Portsmouth", "Bournemouth", "Glasgow", 
             "Newcastle", "Cardiff", "Bristol"];
```

Into this 2d array:

```
twoD = [
        ["Bristol", "Cardiff", "Birmingham", "Luton", "Swansea", "Aberdeen"],
        ["Birmingham", "Manchester", "Southampton", "Chester", "Swansea", "Brighton"],
        ["Portsmouth", "Bournemouth", "Glasgow", "Newcastle", "Cardiff", "Bristol"]
 ];
```

My Code

```
var twoD = [];
var rows = 3;
var cols = 6;

for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    twoD.push( [] );
}

for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (var j =  0; j < cols; j++) {
        twoD[i].push(oneD);
    }
}

console.log(twoD);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split array into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a single for loop. On each iteration, add the `cols` number to `i`, and slice from the `OneD` array the items between `i` and `i` + `cols`. Push the sliced items into the `twoD` array.

```js
var OneD = ["Bristol","Cardiff","Birmingham","Luton","Swansea","Aberdeen","Birmingham","Manchester","Southampton","Chester","Swansea","Brighton","Portsmouth","Bournemouth","Glasgow","Newcastle","Cardiff","Bristol"];

var twoD = [];
var cols = 6;

for(var i = 0; i < OneD.length; i += cols) {
  twoD.push(OneD.slice(i, i + cols));
}

console.log(twoD);
```

Comment: Elegant solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This way it can be done. But be sure to handle left out items. here the array length is exactly 3 parts for 6 items.

```js
var OneD = ["Bristol", "Cardiff", "Birmingham",
  "Luton", "Swansea", "Aberdeen",
  "Birmingham", "Manchester", "Southampton",
  "Chester", "Swansea", "Brighton",
  "Portsmouth", "Bournemouth", "Glasgow",
  "Newcastle", "Cardiff", "Bristol"
];

var TwoD = [];
var cols = 6;
var rows = parseInt(OneD.length / cols, 10); // rows = 3
for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  TwoD.push(OneD.slice(i * cols, (i * cols + cols)));
}
console.log(TwoD);
```

(Or)

```js
var OneD = ["Bristol", "Cardiff", "Birmingham",
  "Luton", "Swansea", "Aberdeen",
  "Birmingham", "Manchester", "Southampton",
  "Chester", "Swansea", "Brighton",
  "Portsmouth", "Bournemouth", "Glasgow",
  "Newcastle", "Cardiff", "Bristol"
];

var TwoD = OneD.join(',').match(/([^,]*,[\w]*){5}[,]*/g).map(function(i) {return i.replace(/,$/, '').split(/,/);});

console.log(TwoD);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second loop is pushing all of `OneD` every time. You need to index the array.

```js
var oneD = ["Bristol","Cardiff","Birmingham","Luton","Swansea","Aberdeen","Birmingham","Manchester","Southampton","Chester","Swansea","Brighton","Portsmouth","Bournemouth","Glasgow","Newcastle","Cardiff","Bristol"];

var twoD = [];
var cols = 6;
var rows = 3;

for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    twoD.push( [] );
}

for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (var j =  0; j < cols; j++) {
        twoD[i].push(oneD[i * cols + j]);
    }
}

console.log(twoD);
```

You can also combine the two loops into one. And also get rid of the index calculation by making the outer loop increment by the number of columns. The version below also doesn't require the 1d array to be exactly `rows * cols` in length.

```js
var oneD = ["Bristol","Cardiff","Birmingham","Luton","Swansea","Aberdeen","Birmingham","Manchester","Southampton","Chester","Swansea","Brighton","Portsmouth","Bournemouth","Glasgow","Newcastle","Cardiff","Bristol"];

var twoD = [];
var cols = 6;
var rows = 3;

for (var i = 0; i < oneD.length; i += cols) {
    var row = [];
    var maxColIndex = Math.min(i+cols, oneD.length);
    for (var j =  i; j < maxColIndex; j++) {
        row.push(oneD[j]);
    }
    twoD.push(row);
}

console.log(twoD);
```